# how to detect which UIViewObject is tapped in swift?

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have UITextVIew in tableViewCell and I am trying save the text. What I did is textViewDidEndEditing to save data. Also I added gesture to detect tap and hidekeyboard for each tap. when User tap from one textview to other, keyboard gets closed and open again. which I don't like. So what I was thinking is to hidekeyboard if current tap is not on the textview. 
Please help me doing this using swift.

Comment: can you post your code? code explains better than words ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tapping outside to close the keyboard will always be difficult.

1. You could try to put the gesture to specific areas and not the textFields, but this is difficult because you need to set more geastures probably
2. Try to find out if the tap gesture is located in the view and if it happens on a textField....  but also not cool
3. Throw away the geasture. For TableViews activate dismiss keyboard on drag. This is a common behavior for removing it. Close the keyboard when pressing return. The delegate call from the textView function "textFieldShouldReturn" should call [textView resignFirstResponder]. Or add a custom keyboard accessory view that has a done button.

On the third case you dont have to fight and hack. 
Feel free to correct me :)